# How to auto indent nested HTML tags in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

I'm trying out VS Code and I used [Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_emmet-snippets) to create a new HTML element with a class. I need to create another nested (child) HTML element inside the original element, but by default, VS Code will not indent for the new element, when you hit enter inside the original element tags. Like if you have `<div class="main"></div>` and you hit enter in between the `div` tags, you'll get -

```
<div class="main">
</div>
```

And then you need to manually go one line up, add tabs and indent for the new HTML element.

In Webstorm, hitting enter in between the parent tags automatically indents for the new child element.

Here are two GIFs which show what I mean.

VS Code -

[image]

Webstorm -

[image]

Is there an extension or some other trick that achieves this feature in VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your looking for this setting

```
{
   ...
   "html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Download an `HTML` formatter Extension. **1th**, download one of the below Extensions:

- Beautify
- JS-CSS-HTML Formatter

OR any other HTML formatter you want. **2th**, in VS Code, go to one of the HTML files you are working. **3th**, Press `ALT + SHIFT + F` then a pop out window appears. **4th** select one of the suggested formatters. All done!

Whenever, you press `ALT + SHIFT + F` in an HTML file, it will be auto indented and beautified.

Comment: Can you really call it auto if you have to press alt+shift+f?

Comment: @spinkus, not really, and I don't suggest truly auto formatter though, it causes too many overheads in vscode, because, it should continuously check the content of an HTML doc.

Answer (score -3):

```
"emmet.useNewEmmet": true;
```

Use this command to enable indent.
Steps:

1) Open "settings.json".

2) Add this code inside { ..... } (Curly Braces).

3) Make sure you add ',' (comma) on the last line if you are adding this code after a certain line in the end.
eg:

```
{
...
...
"editor.fontSize": 17,         <--comma
"emmet.useNewEmmet": true
}
```

4) Save it.

FROM: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30790#issuecomment-317290906

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @LisanE can you please provide more information as to what have you implemented and what result you are getting?